# Gracefully sum multiple columns in AWS Athena excluding nulls

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have to create `total_costs`, `total_proceeds`, and `total_net_loss` columns by adding few other columns in AWS Athena. I also have to replace `nulls` with `zeros`, otherwise the result will be null. I tried to use `sum()` function but it works only on the single column. The following query accomplishes what I want to do but looks very ungracefully. Is there any other, more elegant way  to sum columns in `Athena`?

```sql
SELECT loan_identifier,
       monthly_reporting_period,
       current_actual_upb, 
       current_loan_delinquency_status, 
       (COALESCE(foreclosure_costs,0) + COALESCE(property_preservation_and_repair_costs,0) + COALESCE(asset_recovery_costs,0) + COALESCE(miscellaneous_holding_expenses_and_credits,0) + COALESCE(associated_taxes_for_holding_property,0)) AS total_costs,
       (COALESCE(net_sale_proceeds,0) + COALESCE(credit_enhancement_proceeds,0) + COALESCE(repurchase_make_whole_proceeds,0) + COALESCE(other_foreclosure_proceeds,0)) AS total_proceeds,
       current_actual_upb + (current_actual_upb * ((current_interest_rate/100 - 0.0035)/12)*DATE_DIFF('day', last_paid_installement_date, disposition_date)/30) + (COALESCE(foreclosure_costs,0) + COALESCE(property_preservation_and_repair_costs,0) + COALESCE(asset_recovery_costs,0) + COALESCE(miscellaneous_holding_expenses_and_credits,0) + COALESCE(associated_taxes_for_holding_property,0)) - (COALESCE(net_sale_proceeds,0) + COALESCE(credit_enhancement_proceeds,0) + COALESCE(repurchase_make_whole_proceeds,0) + COALESCE(other_foreclosure_proceeds,0)) AS total_net_loss
FROM performance_data;
```

Comment: `coalesce()` is indeed the way to go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM` and `COALESCE` in combination, like this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(y, 0) + COALESCE(z, 0)) AS aggregate_sum_of_y_and_z
FROM (
  VALUES (1, 2),
         (NULL, 3),
         (2, 1)) AS x (y, z)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll test it Monday.